# How to reference an instance method in another instance method of a different class?

Tags: java, oop, object

Trying to figure it out and couldn't find it anywhere here.If a class is instantiated in a method of another class which is instantiated in a third class which is instantiated in the main method. I know the last statement is long and confusing. so attaching code for a better understanding.

```
public class B {
private String name;
public void setname(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
public String getname(){
    return name;
}
```

}

```
public class C {void method2(){
B b = new B();
b.setname("BBB");
```

}

}

```
public class A {void method1(){
B b=new B();
b.setname("AAA");
C c= new C();

System.out.println(b.getname());
```

}

}

```
public class Testcase {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a=new A();
    a.method1();

}
```

}

How to refer to the getname() method from object b instantiated in the object c.

Comment: **Where** do you want to call that? In the `main()` method, in `method1()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setting class instances as public is wrong, because:

- Everything that is public must be tested.
- It breaks encapsulation
- There are better ways to do it

What you need to do is add a `wrapper method`.

For example in class C:

```
public class C {
    private B b;
    void method2(){
        b = new B();
        b.setname("BBB");
    }
    public void setName(String newName)
    {
         b.setname(newName);
    }
    public String getName()
    {
         return b.getName();
    }
}
```

Public instance way:

```
public class C {
    public B b = new B();
    void method2(){
        b.setname("BBB");
    }
}

public class A {
    public C c = new C();
    public B b =new B();
    void method1(){
        b.setname("AAA");

        System.out.println(b.getname());
    }
}
public class Testcase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a=new A();
        a.c.b.setname("tralala");

    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer anything about this post?

Comment: Making properties private has no effect if there both are a getter and setter

Comment: I have no answer here. I do not understand what the problem is, but yours appear to be just an advice. Much more of a comment.

Comment: @Robin Dijkhof java has no properties, they are called attributes. And they must be private and expose only the functionality needed.

Comment: @Byakuya have you read my answer ? After what you called advice I added the answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I thought of a similar approach by adding a 
"return b.getname;" inside c.method2(). But I wanted to know if we can access the b object methods created in the instance of Class C, directly from class A.

Comment: Also if I need to access 20 such methods from class A, I wouldn't want to change 20 classes if I can just refer to the objects and change code in just 1 class i.e. Class A.

Comment: Well, you can use an IDE and generate the needed code. Or you can just set them public as in the first answer, but that would make your code really bad.

Comment: I added an example of the public way.

Comment: Who is copying now? And who failed to read the question and failed to add `getName()` again? Improve your answer so I can delete the downvote. Your main method is outside of any class. Your parentheses are wrong in class A, and note you can't make two classes public inside one file if you write code like this.

Comment: I edited the post to add the public way as requested by the user. The original question didn't ask for `getName()` it asked for a way to reference a method. And the code is just an example not copy-paste code. So your argument is invalid.

Comment: I also tried the code for Class C that you had attached. I didn't understand as to why we need to define the setname method again in class C. also how can we refer to the getname method of object b instantiated in method2 of class C.

Comment: I defined the `setName()` as an example of how to delegate to the instance of b. Purely informative.

Comment: Thanks very much for the edited response because it put a lot of things in perspective for me but still the original problem remains. We still dont have a way to refer to an object created inside a method of a class. Does this mean that since the object is created and dies with the method I cant refer to the object from the instance of the class C? Or to put it another way object b in method2 of object c cannot be referred to because it dies with method2.

Comment: Yes. If the object is declared only inside method2 and has no outside reference then it dies when method2 ends.

Answer (score 0):

Set your class instances to public like this:

```
public B b = new B();
public C c = new C();
```

Now you can acces them like so:

```
a.b.c.getName();
```